# Duplicating each row in a dataframe with counts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

For each row in a dataframe, I wish to create duplicates of it with an additional column to identify each duplicate.

E.g Original dataframe is

```
A | A 

B | B
```

I wish to make make duplicate of each row with an additional column to identify it. Resulting in:

```
A | A | 1

A | A | 2

B | B | 1

B | B | 2
```

Comment: Seems like a job for np.repeat and count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *`df.reindex`* followed by a *`groupby`* on `df.index`.

```
df = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(2))
df['count'] = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df
   a  b  count
0  A  A      1
1  A  A      2
2  B  B      1
3  B  B      2
```

---

Similarly, using *`reindex`* and *`assign`* with *`np.tile`*:

```
df = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(2))\
       .assign(count=np.tile(df.index, 2) + 1)\
       .reset_index(drop=True)

df

   a  b  count
0  A  A      1
1  A  A      2
2  B  B      1
3  B  B      2
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), for count [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['A', 'B'], 'b': ['A', 'B']})
print (df)
   a  b
0  A  A
1  B  B

df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(2)]
df['new'] = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   a  b  new
0  A  A    1
1  A  A    2
2  B  B    1
3  B  B    2
```

Or:

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(2)]
df['new'] = np.tile(range(int(len(df.index)/2)), 2) + 1
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   a  b  new
0  A  A    1
1  A  A    2
2  B  B    1
3  B  B    2
```

Answer (score 2):

**Setup**
Borrowed from @jezrael

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['A', 'B'], 'b': ['A', 'B']})

   a  b
0  A  A
1  B  B
```

---

**Solution 1**
Create a `pd.MultiIndex` with [**`pd.MultiIndex.from_product`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html)
Then use [**`pd.DataFrame.reindex`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [df.index, [1, 2]],
    names=[df.index.name, 'New']
)

df.reindex(idx, level=0).reset_index('New')

   New  a  b
0    1  A  A
0    2  A  A
1    1  B  B
1    2  B  B
```

---

**Solution 2**
This uses the same `loc` and `reindex` concept used by @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ and @jezrael, but simplifies the final answer by using `list` and `int` multiplication rather than `np.tile`.

```
df.loc[df.index.repeat(2)].assign(New=[1, 2] * len(df))

   a  b  New
0  A  A    1
0  A  A    2
1  B  B    1
1  B  B    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *pd.concat()* to repeat, and then *groupby* with *cumcount()* to count:

```
In [24]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'B'], 'col2': ['A', 'B']})

In [25]: df
Out[25]: 
  col1 col2
0    A    A
1    B    B

In [26]: df_repeat = pd.concat([df]*3).sort_index()

In [27]: df_repeat
Out[27]: 
  col1 col2
0    A    A
0    A    A
0    A    A
1    B    B
1    B    B
1    B    B

In [28]: df_repeat["count"] = df_repeat.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1

In [29]: df_repeat  # df_repeat.reset_index(drop=True); if index reset required.
Out[29]: 
  col1 col2  count
0    A    A      1
0    A    A      2
0    A    A      3
1    B    B      1
1    B    B      2
1    B    B      3
```